# Overlaying line plot on barplot ggplot -

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I am trying to overlay a line plot onto a barplot. I can plot both separately :

```
##plot sites
ggplot(graph, aes(x = Month, y = Anopheles_pos))
+ geom_col(size = 1, color = "darkblue", fill = "white")
```

[image]

```
##plot line
ggplot(graph, aes(x = Month, y = Mean_EVI)) +
 geom_line(size = 1.5, color = "blue", group = 1)
```

[image]

However when I try to plot the line onto the barplot, it is a flat line at the bottom. I tried to deal with the issue by fixing the second y axis (on the right) to be the same scale as the line, but this has not fixed how the line plots.

```
##plot together
    ggplot(graph) + 
      geom_col(aes( x = factor(Month, levels = month.name), y = Anopheles_pos), size = 1,
                    color = "darkblue", fill = "white") + 
      geom_line(aes(x = factor(Month, levels = month.name), y = Mean_EVI), size = 1.5, 
                color = "red", group = 1) +
     scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./50, name = "Mean_EVI"))
```

[image]

One small other issue is I can't figure out how to make the x axis 0-100 as the Anopheles_pos values are percentages.

Thanks in advance!!

DATA:

Mean_EVI : c(0.5687068, 0.5663895, 0.5653846, 0.6504931, 0.584727, 0.5799395,
0.617363, 0.581645, 0.6190386, 0.5208025, 0.6097692, 0.5689)

Anopheles_pos : c(33L, 42L, 38L, 31L, 54L, 47L, 22L, 15L, 2L, 15L, 12L, 19L)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to scale up your Mean_EVI values by 50 to match the `./50` part of your `sec.axis` call.

```
Mean_EVI <- c(0.6190386, 0.5208025, 0.6097692, 0.5689, 0.5687068, 0.5663895, 0.5653846, 0.6504931, 0.584727, 0.5799395, 0.617363, 0.581645)

Anopheles_pos <- c(2L, 15L, 12L, 19L, 33L, 42L, 38L, 31L, 54L, 47L, 22L, 15L)

graph <- data.frame(Mean_EVI, Anopheles_pos, Month = 1:12)

ggplot(graph) + 
  geom_col(aes(x = factor(Month, labels = month.name), y = Anopheles_pos), size = 1,
           color = "darkblue", fill = "white") + 
  geom_line(aes(x =  factor(Month, labels = month.name), y = Mean_EVI*50), size = 1.5, 
            color = "red", group = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./50, name = "Mean_EVI")) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 100))
```

[image]

Comment: You might want to change `factor(Month)` to `factor(months, levels = months)` to make your plot match the OP's

Comment: @AllanCameron I changed the labels - good call.   It was a bit more complicated because OP's data wasn't actually ordered by month

Comment: Thank you so much! Such a simple solution. I have one other small question - how would I set the Anopheles_pos (left hand side) scale to be 0-100?

Comment: @bellbyrne just so I understand you want to just show numbers 0-100 on the Anophele_pos scale (even though the data only goes to 54) or you want to rescale the data itself?

Comment: Yes I'd like to show numbers 0-100 on the scale - as I will be comparing with graphs for a few other species. Thanks

Comment: Okay, I'd edited the answer to do that using `coord_cartesian`